# understanding javascript function call and referance

Tags: javascript, function

I found this browsing:

[What is the difference between a function call and function reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15886272/what-is-the-difference-between-a-function-call-and-function-reference)

After reading the answers there, I did't understand the definition and usage for function references and function calls. Then I searched a lot, but it is still unclear where to use what.

Could you help me understand this by pointing out the differences in concept and usage? I want to make this as a reference for future programers.

Comment: It sounds like what you're missing is the fact that a function is an object in JavaScript.  A reference to a function can be passed around like any variable.  It's only called when parentheses are placed after it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Take this for example:

```
function foo() {
    alert('foo');
    return 'bar';
}
```

First of all, what is a function? It's a routine that can be *called* (or "invoked", or "executed"), and when you do so it usually *does something*, and *returns some value*.

So you have a function named `foo`. You can call it by adding `()` after its name:

```
foo();
```

You can store the return value in a variable, if you assign the result of the invocation to it:

```
var something = foo();
something === 'bar'; // true
```

But that's not all you can do with functions in JavaScript. It's a language where functions are first class citizens, so they can be passed around to other functions, and returned from other functions. They can also be stored as variables. For example:

```
var refToFoo = foo;
```

Now `refToFoo` is the same as `foo`. It's not a copy, it's a *reference* pointing to the same (internal) function object as `foo`. So you can use `refToFoo` just like you would use `foo`:

```
var something = refToFoo();
something === 'bar'; // true
refToFoo === foo; // true; they're the same object
```

Perhaps the most common use to function references is to use them as event listeners:

```
someElement.onclick = foo;
```

Note there is no parentheses above. It we used parentheses, `foo` would be invoked, immediately, and its return value would be assigned to the element's `onclick` method. Since that function returns a string, nothing would happen if the element were clicked. That's a very common mistake newbies do. Another common one is invoking a function instead of passing a reference to setTimeout:

```
setTimeout(foo(), 1000); // WRONG - foo is executed immediately
```

Compare that to:

```
setTimeout(foo, 1000); // RIGHT - we're passing a reference to the function, 
                       // that will be invoked by the js engine after 1000ms
```

I hope this helps clarify your doubt.