# calling function without brackets in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

we use () to invoke the function, But I am confused why we use only function name when we attached function in onclick event in javascript.

```
function a(){
alert(0)
}

document.getElementById('btn').onclick=a


<input value="click" type="button" id="btn" />
```

Comment: There is a good explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19732275/understanding-javascript-function-call-and-referance

Comment: Function is an object as well, so you can refer to it. For example `console.log instanceof Object` == true

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because `a()` executes the function, while `a` is a reference to the function. If you do `console.log(a)` you will see the code of the function

Answer (score 6):

Because we don't want to call the function at that moment, we just want to assign a **reference** to it to the property, so that it can be called *later* on when the event happens.

This would be **incorrect**:

```
document.getElementById('btn').onclick = a();
```

It would call the function *immediately* and assign the return value to `onclick`, which is `undefined`. So nothing would happen when the event takes place.

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = function () {
    alert(0);
};

document.getElementById('btn').onclick = a
```

So you can call the function as above method .Assign function to a variable and calling it from anywhere

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2LcBv/)