# Javascript assign object method

Tags: javascript

Why is assigning method to object property not supported on that way:

```
neki1: pisaniMethod()
```

It seems like when assigning method to object property is not supported with brackets?

```
function pisaniMethod(){return 'testing';}

var person = {        
    neki: pisaniMethod, //this works
    neki1: pisaniMethod()  //this is not working
};
```

I guess I was wrong with this:

```
person.neki1();
```

I've tried to make a function call on neki1.

Comment: `pisaniMethod()` is a function call.. `neki1` will have `testing`..

Comment: What does *work* mean for you? It does assign result of function call to the `neki1`. So, that is wrong?

Comment: Putting `()` after the method name basically says: execute this method *now*! So, in your case value returned by the method will be assigned to `neki1`, while the link to execute the function will be attached to `neki`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between a function call and function reference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15886272/what-is-the-difference-between-a-function-call-and-function-reference)

Comment: `neki1` is not a function. You can't call it

Comment: If result of call `pisaniMethod()` will be function you'll be able to call it. But than in `neki` you'll get function that will return function to call

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because when your assign `pisaniMethod` you assign link to function. In this way `pisaniMethod()` you assign result of function call: `"testing"` in your case.

```js
function pisaniMethod(){return 'testing';};

var person = {        
    neki: pisaniMethod, //this works
    neki1: pisaniMethod()  //this is not working
};

alert(person.neki);
alert(person.neki1);
alert(typeof person.neki);
alert(typeof person.neki1);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function pisaniMethod(){return 'testing';};

var person = {        
    neki: pisaniMethod, //this works
    neki1: pisaniMethod()  //this is not working
};
```

In the first case you are assigning the method. In the second case you are assigning the result retuned by the function since `pisaniMethod()` is a function call, in your case it will be `testing`.