# onclick and eventListener for a dropdown menu not working

Tags: javascript

I have this Dropdown class in which I want to create new element that ,well you guessed it,works exactly like a drop down menu:

```
class Dropdown{
  constructor(name,element,classNa){
    this.classN = classNa;
      var x = new CElement(name,"div",dropdownHeaderStyle,"classN");
      x.display(element);
  }
  dropdown(mes){
    var z = new CElement(mes,"div",dropDownStyle,this.classN);
    z.display(".classN");

  }
}
```

(I have another class CElement that creates elements, using this parameters:value,elementType,elementStyle,classPara = "",and appends it with display funcion, there is no problem with it tho)
the styling:

```
var dropDownStyle = "display:none;";
var show = "display:block;";
```

and the showFunction:

```
function showFunction(selector) {
  document.querySelector(selector).classList.toggle("show");
}
```

The problem happens when I add this bad boy:

```
 x.addEventListener('click',showFunction(".drpDown"));
```

or this:

```
x.onclick = showFunction(".drpDown");
```

It litteraly crashes,If I add that in the constructor, boom after that line nothing works...
The ridiculous thing about this is that I am using another addEventListener('click' ... and that works.What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between a function call and function reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15886272/what-is-the-difference-between-a-function-call-and-function-reference)

Comment: Welcome to SO. You need to learn about the difference between function references (which is what event handlers expect) and function invocations.

Comment: I used even the anonymous function and it doesn't work...
Do I have to add event listeners outside the class or inside the constructor?

Comment: I can't comment on the wider issue, and the reference vs. invocation issue has nothing to do with classes/constructors. What's clear is that ` x.addEventListener('click',showFunction(".drpDown"));` will invoke your event callback immediately, not when the event fires, because you passed it an invocation, not a function reference.

Comment: when I add that bad boy in the constructor it makes dropdown(mes) non existent why is that?