# Chrome Extenstion with Vue Invoking nested methods

Tags: google-chrome-extension, vuejs2

thanks to all in advanced.

I'm trying to build a simple Chrome extension with `vue` using this [Boilerplate](https://github.com/Kocal/vue-web-extension),
but I find it hard to communicate with the `content.js` file and `popup.js` file and passing data between them.

currently I'm trying to pass the total number of `p` tags that are in the current tab.
when I try to invoke a method inside the `sendMessage` function I'm getting an Error saying `this.count is not a function`. I'v figured out that probably the function is not firing because it's nested, but I cant figure out how can invoke the method.

Cheers to all

**popup.js**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p>{{title}}</p>
    <button v-on:click="getCount">click Here</button>
    <p>{{counts}}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      title: "count board",
      counts: ""
    };
  },
  methods: {
    getCount() {
      chrome.tabs.query({ currentWindow: true, active: true }, tabs => {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, "null", this.count);
      });
    }
  },
  count(res) {
    console.log(res.count);
    this.counts = res.count
  }
};
</script>
```

**Content.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (req, sender, sendResponse) {
    const para = document.querySelectorAll('p')
    sendResponse({ count: para.length })
})
```

I'm trying to invoke `this.count` on every button click in `popup.html` and retrieving the total numbers of `P` tags

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: Replace `function(tabs){` with `tabs=>{` P.S. your count() doesn't return anything though...

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks mate, but still this doesn't resolves the issue. 
regrading the count method I know I'm currently want to see if its working, but its even not console logging anything

Comment: Yep I know I'v `inspected` the popup to open the popup console

Comment: You **invoke** `this.count()` without any parameter so `res` is undefined. It's unclear what you're trying to do. Looks like you're confusing function invocation with function reference: you need to remove `()` to make it into a callback.

Comment: [What is the difference between a function call and function reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15886331)

Comment: @wOxxOm cheers you are right I wasn't clear. I will check those link right now.
Iv updated the question with more info maybe now its more clear