# Is func() the same as func?

Tags: javascript, function, variables, binding

While learning JavaScript from an "eloquent" book, I stumbled in this program:

```
function wrapValue(n) {
  let local = n;
  return () => local;
}

let wrap1 = wrapValue(1);
let wrap2 = wrapValue(2);
console.log(wrap1());
// → 1
console.log(wrap2());
// → 2
```

My problem is the output being `wrap1()` rather than `wrap1`.

Is it possible to do even `console.log(wrap1)`?
And if it's possible, are `wrap1()` and `wrap1` the same thing?

EDIT: they flagged the question as duplicate of [What is the difference between a function call and function reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15886272/14170686) however my problem was thinking that in `let wrap1 = wrapValue(1);`, `wrap1` gets a value, but the truth is that it gets a function. That's it. The supposed duplicate have nothing to do with my blindness.

Comment: Duplicate of [What is the difference between a function call and function reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15886272/what-is-the-difference-between-a-function-call-and-function-reference)

Comment: `wrapValue` returns an arrow function `() => ` that's why you need to call it to get result by adding `()`

Comment: @KubwimanaAdrien oh I didn't see that! So I can't do `console.log(wrap1)` because `wrap1` is not the returned value but the returned function, right?

Comment: @Davide that's right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrapValue returns a lambda function, which is what `console.log(wrap1)` will print. `console.log(wrap1())` actually runs that function and prints the result.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So if I get it right, the output would be the same but `wrap1()` does an unnecessary further step, isn't it?

Comment: No, the output is different. The first one prints the function itself, but the second one prints the function's result.

Comment: You mean that in the first case the output would be something like: `function wrapValue(n) {
  let local = n;
  return () => local;
}`?

Comment: No, just () => local. You can check in chrome devtools