# Invoking a method from an Object key

Tags: javascript

I have this class

```
class Dark {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    destroy() {
       console.log("method called")
        console.log(this);
    }
}

const DarkObject = new Dark('DarkObject');

const copyDarkObject = {destroy: DarkObject.destroy}

console.log(copyDarkObject.destroy())

//> method called
// > undefined
```

I stored the reference of the class method to the key of a other Object

`const copyDarkObject = { destroy: DarkObject.destroy };`

the created Object is not the owner of the method so the return is `undefined` thats clear to me but I can still invoke the method from the key with `console.log(copyDarkObject.destroy())`

how is that possible ?

Comment: You still have a function reference and that can still be executed. Why wouldn't that be possible?

Comment: I can not get that its possible to "invoke" the key `copyDarkObject.destroy()`

Comment: But *why*? You seem to understand [function references](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15886272) already because [you weren't surprised by the behaviour of `this`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484). I'm not sure why you expect a function reference to not be callable.

Answer (score 2):

> the created Object is not the owner of the method so the return is `undefined`

No. The statement

```
console.log(copyDarkObject.destroy())
```

logs `undefined` because the destroy method doesn't return anything (since it doesn't use a return statement).

The statement

```
console.log(this)
```

in the destroy method will log your `copyDarkObject`, because `destroy` was called on `copyDarkObject`.

And that's why the log says:

```
method called
Object { destroy: destroy() }       // the object destroy was invoked on
undefined                           // the return value of destoy
```

Answer (score 0):

Class keyword in JavaScript is just syntactic sugar. 
Under the hood it is still prototype based inheritance/system, which allows some extra flexibility.

What exactly happens in your code:

1. You see returned value `undefined` - this is correct, because you never return anything from `destroy()` and Js by default "returns" undefined from functions.
2. You create a new object giving it one property, which is a reference to `darkObject.destroy` - value of `this` pointer/reference in Js depends on how function was called. 
   You can read up on MDN on how built-in function like [bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) or `apply` or `call` work. 
    In this case when you call destroy on `copyOfDarkObject`, `this` points to `copyOfDarkObject`

```js
class Dark {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    destroy() {
       console.log('I am calling destroy on', this);
       return `I am ${this.name}`;
    }
}

const darkObject = new Dark('DarkObject');
const copyOfDarkObject = {destroy: darkObject.destroy}

console.log('returned value', copyOfDarkObject.destroy());
console.log('returned value', darkObject.destroy());

console.log(copyOfDarkObject instanceof Dark);
console.log(darkObject instanceof Dark);
```

Some extra info:

While logging `this` you can see, that *copyOfDarkObject* has one property called `destroy`, but *darkObject* only one called `name`. It is so, because *destroy method* exists on darkObject prototype and you don't see it directly on the object.