# Is it possible to iterate and replace values in an array using forEach?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to iterate an array of strings and replace each element with another string:

```
let arr = ["-","-","-"]

let spaceArr = replaceStringArr.forEach(replaceDash)

const replaceDash = function(index:any, array:any){
   // replace the value of each element containing "-" with "&nbsp"
   I have tried 
   return array[index] = "&nbsp"
   and
   array[index] = "&nbsp"
}
```

I have tried:

```js
const replaceDash = function(index: any, array: any) {
  return array[index] = "&nbsp"
}
```

as well as:

```js
const replaceDash = function(index: any, array: any) {
  array[index] = "&nbsp"
}
```

But I am getting a:

> TypeError: Cannot create property '-' on number '0'

Comment: `function(index:any, array:any)` is the wrong function definition for `forEach`. It's actually `function(element: any, index: number, array: any[])`. Or probably better with generics: `function<T>(element: T. index: number, array: T[])`. So your code right now is trying to assign some properties to a number (second argument is always the index).

Comment: `const replaceDash = function(element:any, index: number, array:any[]){
     return array[index] = "&nbsp"
}`

Comment: But `forEach` doesn't return anything anyways

Comment: Does this answer your question? [For-each over an array in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

[forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) receives the parameter `currentValue` first, `index` second, `array` third. You would need to modify the function as follows:

```
const replaceDash = function(item:any, index:any, array:any){
   // replace the value of each element containing "-" with "&nbsp"
   if(item === "-") array[index] = "&nbsp";
}
```

If I were you I'd also take a look at [map function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), which will give you a new array and seems to be more suited to what you want in less code:

```
let spaceArr = replaceStringArr.map(item => item === '-' ? '&nbsp' : item);
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems you are misunderstanding for `.forEach` works and confusing it for `.map`.

`.forEach` just iterates through an array, it doesn't return anything, while `.map` actually returns the new modified array. If you want `spaceArr` to be the array with modified values, try this:

```js
let arr = ["-","-","-"]

let spaceArr = arr.map(value => {return "&nbsp"})
```

Comment: "*but when you are calling it, it has no parameters.*" [What is the difference between a function call and function reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15886272)

Comment: But OP is *not* calling the function - it's being passed as a reference to `.forEach` and that is entirely correct. Aside from the function definition being wrong and the operations inside, that is but the call `replaceStringArr.forEach(replaceDash)` is 1. syntactically correct 2. has no missing arguments.

Comment: then who is `replaceStringArr`? do you know it is an array? it doesn't even appear in the code, maybe it is a number

Comment: If it isn't an array (or anything with a `.forEach()` method that takes a callback) then it's a) quite exceptional b) there would be a different error. As for what it is - I don't know. It's a prudent guess that it *is* an array, given that 1. it has `Arr` in the name 2. has a `.forEach()` method. 3. said method seems to accept a callback. 4. there is no error indicating the method call or the parameter supplied is wrong. With that said, I don't know what OP wants to do or what the actual code is. I've voted to close for lack of clarity.