# Event listener is not calling the function when it's passed as reference

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll, dom-events

I have a very simple function and very simple event listener in React. Here's the code:

```js
const handleAutoplay = useCallback(() => {
    console.log("test");
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
   console.log("glo");
   window.addEventListener("scroll", handleAutoplay);
   return window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleAutoplay);
},[handleAutoplay])
```

The problem I have is, this event listener doesn't call the function it should. Nothing is happening. However, when I change the code to:

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", () => handleAutoplay());
```

it works like a charm. How come `() => handleAutoplay()` is working when `handleAutoplay` is not?

I tried it with and without `useCallback`, so this is not an issue (AFAIK). Why is this happening? Any explanation? All examples on Stack Overflow and on the internet look exactly like the code I wrote. Am I missing something?

Comment: Refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15886272/what-is-the-difference-between-a-function-call-and-function-reference

Answer (score 1):

Well, I forgot that useEffect should return a function instead of just window.removeEventListener(...).

Comment: Can you please provide a code solution and mark your answer as correct. I have the same problem and I'm struggling to understand what you mean :/