# ReferenceError: req is not defined when I export my function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jwt, express-jwt

I am building a login app using react js node js(express, JWK) but I have a problem when I export my function I recive the error `ReferenceError: req is not defined` but how I defined `req`???

This user.router.js:

```js
const { verifyToken } = require("../middleware/authJwt");
const controller = require("../controllers/user.controller");

module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header(
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
      "x-access-token, Origin, Content-Type, Accept"
    );
    next(req);
  });

  app.get(
    "/api/test/user",
    [verifyToken],
    (controller.userBoard)
  );

};
```

This is authJwt.js:

```js
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const config = require("../config/auth.config.js");

verifyToken = (req, res, next) => {
  let token = req.headers["x-access-token"];

  if (!token) {
    return res.status(403).send({
      message: "Sem Token"
    });
  }

  jwt.verify(token, config.secret, (err, decoded) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(401).send({
        message: "Sem autorização!"
      });
    }
    req.userId = decoded.id;
    next();
  });
};


module.exports = verifyToken();
```

Comment: Look closely: what are you attempting to export? You’re not exporting `verifyToken`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between a function call and function reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15886272/what-is-the-difference-between-a-function-call-and-function-reference)

Answer (score 1):

You're not exporting `verifyToken` in `authJwt.js`. You are exporting a call to this function as a default.

Change

```js
module.exports = verifyToken();
```

to

```js
module.exports = { verifyToken };
```

This way you will simply export the reference.