# How is setInterval invoked here?

Tags: javascript, function, variables, invocation

I have the following Javascript code attached to an HTML document with some CSS styling.

It is simply a box on the screen that changes the style background property colour according to those seen in the array. The id of "colour-changer" is used to access the HTML document and changes it each time the array is iterated.

The function declaration `changeColour();` is used to make this happen by using `colours.length` to count its way through the array and then puts the array value into the HTML, which changes its background colour every 3 seconds.

Once it comes to the end of the array the counter is reset to 0, and it continues around again.

The setInterval method invokes the callback method `changeColour()` every 3 seconds to make this happen.

In order to stop the cycle, an onclick is event is added which invokes a `clearInterval()` method to print out "Timer stopped" inside the box. In order to do this the `setInterval()` method had to be stored in variable `myTimer`.

See the code below. It all works fine but this is not my real problem.

```
let colourChanger = document.getElementById ("colour-changer");
let colours = ["red","blue","green","pink"];
let counter = 0;

function changeColour(){

  if (counter >= colours.length){
   counter = 0;
  }
  
  colourChanger.style.background = colours[counter];
  counter++;

}

let myTimer = setInterval(changeColour, 3000);

colourChanger.onclick = function (){
  
  clearInterval(myTimer);
  colourChanger.innerHTML = "Timer stopped";

}
```

What I cannot understand is the line `let myTimer = setInterval(changeColour, 3000);`

From my understanding if you store a function inside of a variable, it will NOT execute unless called separately. It will just sit there stored in the variable `myTimer`.

There is no `setInterval();` call made outside of the variable anywhere.

MY QUESTION:

How then is this method invoked since it is simply stored inside of the variable `myTimer`?

Comment: The method is not stored inside the variable.  The return of that method is; in this case, `setInterval` returns a numerical identifier for that interval, which can then be used to clear that interval(which is done in the onclick).  This could be realized by simply reading [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval).

Comment: [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval) *This method returns an interval ID which uniquely identifies the interval*

Comment: At least related? [*What is the difference between a function call and function reference?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15886272/what-is-the-difference-between-a-function-call-and-function-reference)

Comment: As a final question. Is ```let myTimer = setInterval(changeColour, 3000);``` still a function expression? Or is it classed as something else?

Answer (score 2):

No, your understanding is wrong.

It executes `setInterval(changeColour, 3000);` *and* stores this particular interval reference ID to `myTimer` to later be used in `clearInterval(myTimer)`

```js
var myTimer = setInterval(() => console.log('ping'), 3000);

setTimeout(() => clearInterval(myTimer), 10000);

console.log('myTimer value: ', myTimer);
```

Comment: So ```clearInterval(myTimer)``` has invoked it? If so, why does it still run even though the onclick event does not happen?

Comment: @martin958 - No, `setInterval` is called by the first line of code in the snippet, and its return value is stored in `myTimer`. `clearInterval(myTimer)` cancels the interval timer that was started by calling `setInterval`.

Comment: You mean ```setInterval``` is called by this line ```let colourChanger = document.getElementById ("colour-changer");``` ?

Comment: @martin958 No.  `setInterval` is called by the line that sets the variable `myTimer`.

Answer (score 1):

`setInterval()` function will return `IntervalID`, It will set execution interval for given `milliseconds`.

> In your case once this line is executed it will start executing `changeColour` function every `3000ms` / `3 seconds` and return `IntervalID`.

Now this `IntervalID` is used to stop executing your function every `3 seconds` in the `future`.

to stop executing you can use `clearInterval(IntervalID)`.

if any doubts please comment.

Comment: yes because the function was assigned to `f` as it was function declaration, but `setInterval`  It itself is a function call `setInterval(changeColour, 3000);` you are calling `setInterval` function and not declaring it so it executed inline and return ID.

Comment: Why is setInterval a function call when let f = function foo(){console.log("Hello");}; is only a declaration?

Comment: @martin958 because in `f=function foo(){ }` you have the *keyword* `function` which says "this is declaring a function"

Comment: So let f=foo () { } will be invoked if the function keyword is left out?

Comment: No, that will give a `unexpected token` error (ie a syntax error).  And if you make it `let f = foo();` then it will give `foo is not defined`

Comment: And why should ```let f = foo();``` not call the foo function? Presuming the function foo was already declared elsewhere?

Comment: Yes, it would *if* it was previously defined.   `let f=foo;` would *not* call it, but you could do `f();` later which is the similar scenario to `f=function foo(){}` but with a predefined function `foo`

Answer (score 1):

> In order to do this the setInterval() method had to be stored in variable myTimer.

No, the *return value* of `setInterval` is stored in `myTimer` by that code. `setInterval` is called (it has `(/*...*/)` after it, which calls it).

> From my understanding if you store a function inside of a variable, it will NOT execute unless called separately.

That's correct, but that's not what that line of code is doing. This code:

```
let myTimer = setInterval(changeColour, 3000);
```

*calls* `setInterval` and stores its return value in `myTimer`, exactly the way:

```
let x = example();
```

*calls* `example` and stores its return value in `x`.

It's the `changeColour` function that is only referenced, not called, by that code (there's no `(/*...*/)` after it). Doing that passes `changeColour` into `setInterval`, so that `setInterval` knows what function to call every three seconds or so.

So in that code, `setInterval` is called, and `changeColour` is just referenced (it's called later by the timer mechanism).