# How to write a function that only invokes a callback once, then returns the result of calling the function the first time, every subsequent calling

Tags: javascript, closures

How to write a function that returns a callback, but only the result of the first time calling the callback.

Returns a function that is restricted to invoking func once.
Repeat calls to the function return the value of the first call.

```js
function once(func) {
 let result = func
 let counter = 0
 //let result 
 function inner (n) {
   counter++
   if (counter = 1) {
     return func
    }
   if (counter > 1) {
     return result
   }
 }
 return inner
}
```

I can't put my finger on what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: It's not really clear what you are trying to do. Your demo doesn't call `once` at all. In the function you cope `func` to `result` and then never change either so you just have to variables with the same value. You've go an assignment in the middle of an if where I'd expect a comparison.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track using the closure, you just have to

1. *Call* `func` at least once (right now you just refer to it; [more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15886272/what-is-the-difference-between-a-function-call-and-function-reference))
2. Remember the result of that for subsequent invocations

You don't need a counter, just some kind of flag; perhaps `func` itself, which you could clear:

```
function once(func) {
    let result;
    return () => {
        if (func) {
            result = func();
            func = null;
        }
        return result;
    };
}
```

```js
function once(func) {
    let result;
    return () => {
        if (func) {
            result = func();
            func = null;
        }
        return result;
    };
}

const fn = () => {
    console.log("fn called");
    return 42;
};

console.log("Getting the function");
const f = once(fn);
console.log("Doing first call");
console.log(f());
// => fn called
// => 42
console.log("Doing second call");
console.log(f()); // 42
// => 42
console.log("Doing third call");
console.log(f()); // 42
// => 42
```