# Javascript addEventListener isn't working

Tags: javascript, html

here is HTML:

```
<div class="args-container">
    <button type="button" id="nuclear">click to see nuclear</button>
    <button type="button" id="geothermal">click to see geothermal</button>
</div>
```

here is javascript:

```
const args = Array.from(document.querySelector(".args-container").children);

args.forEach(e => e.addEventListener("click", myFunc()));
```

If i click on a button **"myFunc()"** isn't working

Comment: The second argument to `addEventListener()` should be a **reference to a function**.  You're passing in the *result* of calling `myFunc()`, not a reference to `myFunc()`.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15886272/what-is-the-difference-between-a-function-call-and-function-reference