# Arrow functions behaviour inside promises

Tags: javascript, console.log, arrow-functions

Q1.) Why I am getting undefined if i pass console.log in then block in a promise chian?

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  console.log(4)
  resolve(5)
  console.log(6)
}).then(() => console.log(7))
.catch(() => console.log(8))
.then(() => console.log(9))
.catch(() => console.log(10))
.then(() => console.log(11))
.then(console.log)
.finally(() => console.log(12))
```

Output:

4
6
7
9
11
undefined
12

Q2.) However if I pass console.log in then block using arrow function, i get nothing as output wrt that then block.

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  console.log(4)
  resolve(5)
  console.log(6)
}).then(() => console.log(7))
.catch(() => console.log(8))
.then(() => console.log(9))
.catch(() => console.log(10))
.then(() => console.log(11))
.then(()=>console.log)
.finally(() => console.log(12))
```

Output:
4
6
7
9
11
12

Can anyone explain this behaviour?

I am just curious to understand this behaviour of our beloved JS.

Comment: `console.log` has no return value. From the first `then` on there is nothing but undefined being passed to the next then.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [*What is the difference between a function call and function reference?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15886272/what-is-the-difference-between-a-function-call-and-function-reference)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.then(console.log)` passes the `console.log` function into `then`, telling it to call that function when the promise you called `.then` on is fulfilled. When that happens, it will be passed the fulfillment value (in this case, that value is `undefined`), and so `console.log` outputs `undefined`. (The fulfillment value is `undefined` because the promise was created by `.then(() => console.log(11))`, which fulfills its promise with the result of calling `console.log`, which is always `undefined`.)

`.then(() => console.log)` passes an arrow function into `.then` instead. When that function is called, it returns `console.log` (the function) without *calling* it. Nothing ever calls it, and so you don't see `undefined`.

This doesn't have anything to do with promises. It's just the difference between this:

```js
function then(callback) {
    callback(undefined);
}

then(console.log);
```

and this:

```js
function then(callback) {
    callback(undefined);
}

then(() => console.log);
```

Answer (score 0):

A1)
`.then(() => console.log(11))` is the same as `.then(() => { return console.log(11) })` and console.log returns void/undefined
-> so you log in the line `.then(console.log)` the returnvalue from the last one and this is undefined

A2)
`.then(()=>console.log)` at this point you dont call the function