# Stringing Callbacks together across multiple functions

Tags: javascript, callback

I want to string functions together using callbacks - which I am still struggling to learn.  Essentially I want the functions to execute one after another in order a, b and c.  When I run the basic code below, my output is

poll b
poll a

poll c is never returned.

What am I doing wrong that makes the order wrong and c to never be returned?

```js
function a(callback) {
  console.log('poll a')
  if (callback) {
    callback(b())
  }
}

function b(callback2) {
  console.log('poll b')
  if (callback2) {
    callback2(c());
  }
}

function c() {
  console.log('poll c')

}
a(b())
```

Comment: `callback2` is undefined. None of the functions return anything. Also, the functions are being called immediately instead of being passed.

Comment: The callback2 dont exist, for a, callback is b, and for b there is not a callback ,  it must be: 
a(b(callbackhere));

Comment: maybe it would help knowing that a function is a data type in js and that those arguments are indeed supposed to hold such data type. `a(b())` is calling `a` passing the returning value from `b()` . when defining a function like that you are actually storing a function object in a variable named like the function name.. so maybe you wanted to do `a(b)` instead.. but I didn't go further

Comment: the lesson is don't just randomly try.. learn about js functions!

Comment: @zGilexx Got it.  This works c(b(a())) and gives me the desired output

Comment: @user2828701 with `c(b(a()))` you might as well remove all the if statements and just call them one after another `a(); b(); c();`

Comment: but you still didn't get the point since you have things like this `callback2(c());` but I'm glad you think you have the desired output. you can drop the whole callback thing because it's totally messed up and it pollutes what you think you achieved

Comment: @DiegoD Help me understand a bit more.  Is callback2(c()) not executing c when b is done?  I want b() to execute only after a is finished.  and I want c() to execute only after b() is finished.

Comment: when you do `a(b(c()))` you are actually just doing 3 invocations and they will be performed in reverse order: c,b,a. The callback you pass is always undefined.. because you are not passing any callback. I tried to explain but you just skipped that part. You have to study what a function data type is to understand that point.

Comment: Relevant: [What is the difference between a function call and function reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15886272)

Comment: @DiegoD Thanks for trying to help.  I'll keep playing around with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the above code, you are calling b inside a's function call which calls function b first and prints **"poll b"**. But there is **no argument passed to function b** here so callback will be empty so the condition becomes false and function c will not be called. The **return value of b will be null** here.

Once function b is executed and returns null, function a will be called as **a(null)**. While executing function a, **"poll a"** will be printed next and the callback variable will be checked for truthiness. As callback has null, again the condition fails and the execution stops there after calling a.

So the code needs a little modification as to work in the specified manner.

```
function a(callback) {
    console.log('poll a')
    if (callback) {
        callback(c)
    }
}

function b(callback2) {
    console.log('poll b')
    if (callback2) {
        callback2();
    }
}

function c() {
    console.log('poll c')
}

a(b)
```

The above code is going to print the output as required.

Answer (score 0):

```
            async.waterfall([
                function (callback) {
                        console.log('poll a')
                        callback();

                }, function (callback) {
                        console.log('poll b')
                        callback();

                }, function (callback) {
                        console.log('poll c')
                        callback();
                }

            ], function (err) {
                console.log('poll Finished')
                callback(err);
            });
```

Use async package. In async library there is a way as:

> async.waterfall

Using this you can add as many as functions and run it in series/waterfall model(Lets say function a,then b and goes on).Like in the code snippet above add as many as functions you needed and once callback() is called then only it will go to second function then to third and like that.And at last it reaches the function error part if there is error you can pass error to callback to exit from there.Check this out will be better and more clean way to do your requirement.