# function with parameters not working with onclick and work with console.log only

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, console, arguments

here is the code

```
<button id="show">Show</button>
<script>
function sayMessage (fName, lName) {
  let message = `Hello`;
  function concatMsg() {
    message = `${message} ${fName} ${lName}`;
  }
  concatMsg();
  return message;
}

document.getElementById("show").onclick = sayMessage("Moro", "Mero"); // Not Working!!

console.log(sayMessage("Moro", "Mero"));

</script>
```

It prints Hello Mohamed Shaker in the console. but when I try it using the button to show it in my html it doesn't work!

I'm trying to get the same result that appeared in the console but in my html page and it didn't work!

Comment: `.onclick = sayMessage("Moro", "Mero");` **calls** your function, and then assigns its return value to `onclick`, exactly the way `a = b()` **calls** `b`, then assigns its return value to `a`. See the [linked questions' answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15886272/what-is-the-difference-between-a-function-call-and-function-reference) and [any of several others](/search?q=%5Bjs%5D+event+handler+with+arguments) for what to do instead (basically: wrap it in a function, and assign that function as the event handler).