# Promises: loop an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I created a node script that contains a `main` function that needs compute a result.
Basically there is an array of strings and I need to loop on this array and for each values, call a promise function that returns a result.

Below a very simple example:

```js
const PEOPLE_ADDRESSES = ['streetD', 'street2', 'streetA']

async function main() {
  PEOPLE_ADDRESSES.forEach(async (address, i) => {
    console.log(`- person #${i}`)
    await fetchPerson(address).then((person) => {
      console.log(person)
    })
  })
}

function fetchPerson(address) {
  const result = {
    address,
    age: Math.round(Math.random() * 100),
  }
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve(result), 3000))
}

main()
```

When I run it, I get:

```
- person #0
- person #1
- person #2
{ address: 'streetD', age: 91 }
{ address: 'street2', age: 83 }
{ address: 'streetA', age: 52 }
```

but I would like to have:

```
- person #0
{ address: 'streetD', age: 91 }
- person #1
{ address: 'street2', age: 83 }
- person #2
{ address: 'streetA', age: 52 }
```

What am I wrong? I think there is a mistake using promises.. Can someone help me?

---

I tried:

```js
async function main() {
  PEOPLE_ADDRESSES.forEach(async (address, i) => {
    console.log(`- person #${i}`)
    const person = await fetchPerson(address)
    console.log('person: ', person)
  })
}

function fetchPerson(address) {
  const result = {
    address,
    age: Math.round(Math.random() * 100),
  }
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve(result), 1500))
}
```

but I get the same result..

Comment: When you're using `await`, there's no reason to mix your code with `.then()` handling of Promise results. The `await` will make that much simpler.

Comment: `const res = await Promise.all(PEOPLE_ADDRESSES.map(address => fetchPerson(address)))`. now res is an array with 3 elements

Comment: @T.J.Crowder my bad yeah

Comment: Side note about the placeholder code: `return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve(result), 3000))` is calling `resolve` **immediately**,not later when the timer fires. Why: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15886272/what-is-the-difference-between-a-function-call-and-function-reference

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thank you! I edited my main message adding the code that I'm testing now. Sorry, but I don't understand what I'm doing wrong

Comment: @cmgchess thank you! I edited my main message adding the code that I'm testing now. Sorry, but I don't understand what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Oh, my fault! the problem was the `forEach`!! I replaced it with a `for..of` and it works. Than you!